# ODP.Net new OracleConnection "Value cannot be null Parameter Name: path"

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a project using ODP.Net version 12.2.1100.  This project was working fine until opening today.  The following line of code is causing the error:

```
using (var cn = new OracleConnection("User Name={userID}, etc, etc"))
```

The error being returned is:

`Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path`

Inner exception 
   `at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)`

Things I have tried so far to resolve the issue:

1. Changed connection string from EZ Connect to full Oracle string
2. Uninstalled and resintalled Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (through NuGet)
3. Ensured all config files were up to date
4. Created a new simple test console project (which connected fine)

Comment: Always the same error? If yes, it seems to be unrelated to `OracleConnection`, esp. when you use the full Oracle string.

Comment: Yeah always the same error.  I actually changed to an empty constructor and the same error.  My instinct tells me its some configuration missing but nothing has appeared to change...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. It occurred also with the Managed Data Provider and it happens with the first Oracle class that gets instantiated, e.g. `OracleParameter`. But it only happens in the debugger of a unit test or in other cases where `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns null.

The call stack of the error gave me a hint: It calls `System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`. This throws the exception. By looking at the Oracle code I found a try-catch around it that should catch the exception but for some reason that sometimes fails.
In another project I get the same exception but this time it gets caught before it hits my code. Strange.
The following work around works for me:

```cs
        try
        {
            new OracleDependency();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

This triggers the static constructor of `ConfigBaseClass` and ignores the error. It is sufficient to call this once in your code, e.g. also in a static constructor. I used `OracleDependency` as it doesn't require a `Dispose` as most other Oracle classes.

Answer (score 0):

So next on my list was checking in my project and asking a colleague to open it to determine if the problem travelled with the code.  He was able to execute successfully.  I deleted my working copy and pulled it down from TFS, everything started working again.  I suspect that something was corrupt in the `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in my integration test project. After deleting the bin folder and rebuilding, the error disappeared.